# Error ? A subset $A$ of $ \mathbb R^p$ S.T $A^o = \phi$ and $A^- = \mathbb R^p$ where $A^o$ is interior of $A$ and $A^-$ is closure of $A$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Can there be a subset $A$ of $ \mathbb R^p$ such that $A^o = \phi$ and $A^- = \mathbb R^p$ where $A^o$ refers to the interior of $A$ and $A^-$ refers to closure of $A$

**Attempt:** By definition : $(i) ~A^-$ refers to the intersection of all closed sets which contain $A$ and

$(ii)~A^o$ refers to the union of all open sets contained in $A$.

$A^-= \mathbb R^p$ means intersection of all closed sets containing $A = A_1~ \bigcap ~A_2 ~\bigcap ~\cdots~  =\mathbb R^p$ where $A_1,A_2, \cdots ~$ are closed sets in $\mathbb R^p$

> Is this possible only when $A_1=A_2= \cdots= \mathbb R^p$?

which means there is no proper closed set in $\mathbb R^p$ which contains $A$.

Hence $A = \mathbb R^p$ and then $A^- = \mathbb R^p \ne \phi$.

Hence, the given codition is not possible.

Is there a mistake in my inference? Please help me find it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's absolutely true that $\overline A = \mathbb R^p$ means that no proper closed subset of $\mathbb R^p$ contains $A$. But this certainly doesn't imply that $A = \mathbb R^p$. Think about $p = 1$ and $A = \mathbb Q$.

Comment: Suppose $A = \mathbb Q$ then $A^-= $ intersection of all closed sets containing $\mathbb Q$. We need to prove that $A^- = \mathbb Q$

Comment: No, you will have $\overline A = \mathbb R$. Do you know the description of $\overline A$ in terms of limits of sequences?

Comment: ya sorry. $A^- = \mathbb R$ . I do know that $A^-$ is the set of all points of $A$ and limit points of $A$. However, the book which I am reading has strangely not introduced this . So, I am wondering if there's a method to infer without using this definition. Thanks

Comment: @PseudoNeo When $A^-=\mathbb R$ how does $A^o$ become $=\phi?$ .

Comment: Well it's not true for all such $A$, of course. But with $A = \mathbb Q$ or $A = \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$, for example, you have both $\overline A = \mathbb R$ and $A^\circ = \emptyset$.

Comment: Oh okay.. true..

Comment: And to prove that $\overline {\mathbb Q} = \mathbb R$, for example, take a closed set $F \subset \mathbb R$ such that $\mathbb Q \subset F$. What can you say of the complementary $\mathbb R \setminus F$?

Comment: $R$ \ $F$ is open ..

Comment: @PseudoNeo So, what we need to prove is that $F=\mathbb R$ right?

Comment: Let $A$ be a closed set containing $\mathbb{Q}$. Then $A^c$ is open. Suppose there is an $a\in A^c$. Then there is an open interval $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)\in A^c$. So there is an open interval with no elements in $A$ and this implies there is an open interval with no elements in $\mathbb{Q}$, which is impossible since the rationals are dense. Thus $A^c=\emptyset$, so $A=\mathbb{R}$. So the only closed set containing $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{R}$, so cl$(\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{R}$.